# vertically center elements. line-height vs padding

Tags: html, padding, css

I'm trying to find the best way to vertically center two left floated elements.

`center with padding:` http://jsfiddle.net/fUmMM/14/

`center with line-height:` http://jsfiddle.net/fUmMM/15/

Both versions work with newer browsers but what is with olders like IE8? Is it better to calculate the exact padding to support old browsers? The line-height version feels more like a hack for me but its faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line height and padding are typically both ok in IE8. [It was buggy in IE6 though](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/lineheightbug.html).

Aside from that, prefer padding anyway. Unless you *know* that your content will never have to break lines, don't use `line-height`, because once the content's on two lines or more, the effect is a lot more broken with line-height wrapping into multiple lines than it is using the padding method:

line-height: http://jsfiddle.net/fUmMM/16/

[image]

---

### vs

padding: http://jsfiddle.net/fUmMM/17/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
center with line-height: http://jsfiddle.net/fUmMM/15/
```

Center with line height is better way for vertically center tow left floated elements

Comment: A valid reason is required. He is not asking for suggestions